# Generating Multiple Subsets in R

Tags: r

I have a large sequence of bytes, and I would like to generate a list containing an arbitrary number of subsets of that sequence.  I suspect I need to use one of the apply functions, but the trick is that I need to iterate over the vector of starting positions, **not** the sequence itself.

Here's an example of how I want it to work --

```
extrct_by_mod <- function(x, startpos, endpos, lrecl)
{
  x[1:length(x) %% lrecl %in% startpos:endpos]
}

tmp_seq <- letters[1:25]

startpos <- c(0, 2)
endpos   <- c(1, 5)
lrecl    <- 5

list_one   <- extrct_by_mod(x=tmp_seq, startpos=startpos[1], endpos=endpos[1], lrecl=lrecl)
list_two   <- extrct_by_mod(x=tmp_seq, startpos=startpos[2], endpos=endpos[2], lrecl=lrecl)

what_i_want <- list(list_one, list_two)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just add more values to startpos and endpos, thus automatically generate more subsets to add to my list.  Note that the subsets will not be the same length, and in some cases, not even the same type.

My datasets are fairly large, so something that scales well would be ideal.  I realize that this could be done with a loop, but I'm understanding that you generally want to avoid looping in R.

Thank you!

Comment: The vector `1:length(x) %% lrecl` is going to be a constant so you could pre-calculate that and save an operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving some time by pre-calculating the modulo-selection index:

```
> cats <- 1:length(tmp_seq) %% lrecl
> mapply(function(start,end) { tmp_seq[cats %in% start:end]} , startpos, endpos)
[[1]]
 [1] "a" "e" "f" "j" "k" "o" "p" "t" "u" "y"

[[2]]
 [1] "b" "c" "d" "g" "h" "i" "l" "m" "n" "q" "r" "s" "v" "w" "x"
```

(It is not correct that R apply functions are any faster than equivalent loops.)